# How to build mysql query string in more beautiful way in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is how I do this now:

```
sql_q = """INSERT INTO measurements(time, voltage, current, frequency, powerActive, powerReactive, powerApparent, powerFactor, phaseAngle, totalFAE, totalRAE, totalFRE, totalRRE, phase)
        VALUES ('%s', %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f)""" % (now, j['phases'][0]['voltage'], j['phases'][0]['current'], j['phases'][0]['frequency'], j['phases'][0]['powerActive'], j['phases'][0]['powerReactive'], j['phases'][0]['powerApparent'], j['phases'][0]['powerFactor'], j['phases'][0]['phaseAngle'], j['phases'][0]['totalForwardActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][0]['totalReverseActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][0]['totalForwardReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][0]['totalReverseReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][0]['number'])
sql_q += """, ('%s', %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f)""" % (now, j['phases'][1]['voltage'], j['phases'][1]['current'], j['phases'][1]['frequency'], j['phases'][1]['powerActive'], j['phases'][1]['powerReactive'], j['phases'][1]['powerApparent'], j['phases'][1]['powerFactor'], j['phases'][1]['phaseAngle'], j['phases'][1]['totalForwardActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][1]['totalReverseActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][1]['totalForwardReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][1]['totalReverseReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][1]['number'])
sql_q += """, ('%s', %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f)""" % (now, j['phases'][2]['voltage'], j['phases'][2]['current'], j['phases'][2]['frequency'], j['phases'][2]['powerActive'], j['phases'][2]['powerReactive'], j['phases'][2]['powerApparent'], j['phases'][2]['powerFactor'], j['phases'][2]['phaseAngle'], j['phases'][2]['totalForwardActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][2]['totalReverseActiveEnergy'], j['phases'][2]['totalForwardReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][2]['totalReverseReactiveEnergy'], j['phases'][2]['number'])
```

this table have one more column id which is auto increment int.
Is there a way to do this in better/smarter way?

Comment: Write your data into a file and then [load data from file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are open to SQL injection, you should use [parameterised queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) to begin with instead of string interpolation. Further, the Python MySQL connector (should that be what you're using) supports [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) for cases like this. Your final code should look something like:

```
stmt = 'INSERT INTO measurements (time, voltage, current, ...) '
       'VALUES (%(time)s, %(voltage)s, %(current)s, ...)'

# Create a list of dicts, each containing all keys for %(...)s placeholders above
values = [{'time': now, **vals} for vals in j['phases']]

cursor.executemany(stmt, values)
```

You may also be able to skip the use of `now` entirely. If your database column is a `DATETIME` type or similar, you can use `... VALUES(NOW, ...`, and MySQL will insert the current time. You can even set that as the `DEFAULT` value for that column and skip it entirely during an `INSERT`. In that case, you don't even need to change those dicts you already have, and just do:

```
stmt = 'INSERT INTO measurements (time, voltage, current, ...) '
       'VALUES (NOW, %(voltage)s, %(current)s, ...)'

cursor.executemany(stmt, j['phases'])
```

Comment: using `DATETIME` from MySQL will give me different time for three records which must always have exactly the same time. I have 3 sets of values every measurements and each of it need to have exatc same time in MySQL for future MySQL queries. executemany will add it one by one not all 3 at once, am I right?

Comment: Read the last few paragraphs on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html.